# Перегрузка строкового класса

Tags: c++, строки, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Форумчане, помогите пожалуйста с задачей. Никак не пойму как перегрузить часть операторов. **Вот условие задачи :**

```
Создать динамический класс для работы со строками . Максимальная длина последовательности - 254. Первый байт должен содержать информацию о фактическом количестве элементов массива. Осуществить перегрузки операций:

"=" - Присвоение ,
"+" - Конкатенация (соединение ) строк ,
" < =" - Отношение "меньше или равно" ,
" > =" - Отношение "больше или равно" ,
" ==" - Отношение "равно" ,
" ! =" - Отношение " не равно" .
" < =" - Отношение включения ( проверяется, есть множество, предоставлена ​​левым операндом , подмножеством множества , предоставленной правым ) ,
" ==" - Эквивалентность множеств ,
" ! =" - Неэквивалентность множеств ,
" <<" - Принадлежность (проверяется , принадлежит значение , предоставленное левым операндом , к множеству , предоставленной правым операндом ) .
```

****У меня не получается эта часть(не пойму как реализовать):****

```
" < =" - Отношение включения ( проверяется, есть множество, предоставлена ​​левым операндом , подмножеством множества , предоставленной правым ) ,
" ==" - Эквивалентность множеств ,
" ! =" - Неэквивалентность множеств ,
" <<" - Принадлежность (проверяется , принадлежит значение , предоставленное левым операндом , к множеству , предоставленной правым операндом ) .
```

**Вот то, что у меня получилось:**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

class String
{
public:
       char *str;
     String();

     void operator= (String &obj2);
    void operator+ (String &obj2);
     void operator<= (String &obj2);
      void operator>= (String &obj2);
       void operator== (String &obj2);
        void operator!= (String &obj2);

     //Консольный Ввод и Вывод
     friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, String obj);
     friend istream &operator>>(istream &stream, String obj);

};
//Конструктор
String::String()
{
    str=new char[255];
}

//Присвоение
void String::operator=(String &obj2){
       strcpy(str,obj2.str);
}

void String::operator+(String &obj2){
       strcat(str,obj2.str);
}

void String::operator<=(String &obj2){
    int t = atoi(str);
    int k = atoi(obj2.str);
      if (t<=k){
        cout<<"Да 1 <= 2"<<endl;
      }
      else
        cout<<"Лож"<<endl;
}

void String::operator>=(String &obj2){
      int t = atoi(str);
    int k = atoi(obj2.str);
      if (t>=k){
        cout<<"Да 1 >= 2"<<endl;
      }
      else
        cout<<"Лож"<<endl;
}

void String::operator==(String &obj2){
      if( strcmp(str,obj2.str)){
        cout<<"Не равны!"<<endl;
        cout<<str;
        cout<<obj2.str;
      }
      else
        cout<<"Равны!"<<endl;
}

void String::operator!=(String &obj2){
       strcmp(str,obj2.str);
        if( !strcmp(str,obj2.str)){
        cout<<"Равны!"<<endl;
      }
      else
        cout<<"Не равны!"<<endl;
}

//Описание консольного вывода
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, String obj)
{
    stream<<obj.str;
    return stream;
}

//Описание консольного ввода
istream &operator>>(istream &stream, String obj)
{
    stream>>obj.str;
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    String obj1, obj2;
    int deistv;
    cout<<"Введите строку"<<"\n"<<"-> ";
    cin>>obj1;
    cout<<"\nВаша строка"<<"\n->";
    cout<<obj1;
    cout<<"Введите вторую строку"<<"\n"<<"-> ";
    cin>>obj2;
    cout<<"\nВаша строка"<<"\n->";
    cout<<obj2;

    while (1){
    cout << "\n"<<"Выберите действие (перегрузку):\n";
                cout << "1. Демонстрация присвоения"<<endl;
                cout << "2. Сложить (+)"<<endl;
                cout << "3. Сравнить (==)"<<endl;
                cout << "4. Сравнить (!=)"<<endl;
                cout << "5. <="<<endl;
                 cout << "6. >="<<endl;
                cout << "7. Выход из программы"<<endl;
                cout << "7. Выход из программы"<<endl;
    cout<<"->";
    cin>>deistv;
    if (deistv==1){
        obj2=obj1;
        cout<<"Второй объект содержит строку: ";
        cout<<obj2;
                  }

if (deistv==2){
        obj2+obj1;
        cout<<"Второй объект содержит строку: ";
        cout<<obj2;
                  }

        if (deistv==3){
        obj2==obj1; }

        if (deistv==4){
        obj2!=obj1;

                  }

                  if (deistv==5){
        obj1<=obj2;

                  }

                    if (deistv==6){
        obj1>=obj2;

                  }

    if (deistv==7){
         system("PAUSE");
        return 0;}
}
}
```

**Я не пойму как перегрузить остальные операторы....** Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @battlemanls скажите пожалуйста, как это может быть - вы якобы смогли перегрузить несколько операторов, и понятия не имеете как сделать практически то же самое еще раз? Как-то неправдоподобно

Comment: Я понимаю как перегружать операторы, и понимаю первую часть задачи, где нужно сравнить, а вот вторую часть условия я не понимаю(отношение включения, неэквивалентность множеств,  принадлежность)

Comment: Получается, что эквивалентность множеств это тоже самое что и (" ==" - Отношение "равно"). Но я все же  не понимаю как проверить (отношение включения  и Принадлежность)

Comment: А вас не смущает, что надо перегрузить одни и те же операторы двумя разными способами? По-моему вторая часть относится к другому заданию, в котором надо реализовать класс "множество".

Comment: так, подождите. Вы что вообще реализуете? Строки или множества?

Comment: Вторая часть задания относится тоже к строкам(судя по условию). Пытаюсь реализовать строки...

Comment: судя по условию вторая часть относится к множествам (о чем довольно недвусмысленно говорят условия). Более того, операции строк со множествами - это вообще что-то странное и вряд ли имеющее смысл

Comment: операции строк со множествами (вторая часть задачи)

Comment: что конкретно?

Comment: >операции строк со множествами (вторая часть задачи)

знаете, можно, пожалуй, и зайца научить курить. Но зачем? То же самое касается и ваших строк со множествами. Это разные типы данных с разной внутренней логикой и поведением. Совмещать их неправильная идея. Вы явно ошибаетесь - у вас в условии нигде не сказано, что операции со множествами нужны именно в классе строк. 
Цитата: 

>проверяется, есть множество, предоставлена ​​левым операндом , подмножеством множества , предоставленной правым

здесь ясно сказано, что и первый и второй операнды - это множества. Никаких строк.

Answer (score 1):

[[@battlemanls](/users/17254/battlemanls)](/users/17254/battlemanls), стоит сохранять исходную семантику операций, поэтому:

= - должна возвращать присвоенное значение, т.е. String & (еще лучше const String &), например, так: return *this;

'+ - такая конкатенация подразумевает результат как новый объект, т.е. String

<=, >= - если это рассматривать как вхождение подстроки в строку, то используйте strstr

<=, >=, ==, != - операции отношений, возвращающие *логическое* значение - bool (или int, смотря какой у вас компилятор)

Передавайте параметр как const String &, т.к. правый параметр не изменяется, все операции (кроме =) реализуйте как const (константные методы), т.к. левый операнд в них тоже не изменяется.

И **уберите вывод на экран** в этих операциях - достаточно возвращаемого значения (истина/ложь).

В операции "+" следите за длиной результирующей строки - она ограничена по условию задачи.

В операциях с потоком << и >> передавайте параметр как const String & - незачем дублировать объект в стеке. Тем более, эти копии будут некорректны.

Реализуйте конструктор копирования и деструктор - *обязательно*, у вас просто классический случай.

Конечно, юнит-тест надо будет переписать, зато можно будет писать что-то типа

```
if (obj1+obj2 == obj3 && obj1<=obj4)
    obj1=obj4;
```

**UPD:**

А еще забыли, что по заданию первый байт, т.е. str[0] - количество символов в строке, тогда сама строка начинается с str+1. Также надо учесть нуль-терминатор (нулевой байт, завершающий строку). Максимальная длина строки по заданию 254, следовательно, создавать надо str[256].

Comment: Да...Засада...